# Why doesn't this if/else work in ejs?

Tags: node.js, client, ejs

```
<% if (title != undefined) { %>
    <%= title %>
<% } elseif(title == undefined) { %>
    <%= "Trendy Analytics" %>
<% } %>
```

Why doesn't this sort of thing work in an .ejs file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `else if` not `elseif`:

```
<% if (title != undefined) { %>
    <%= title %>
<% } else if(title == undefined) { %>
    <%= "Trendy Analytics" %>
<% } %>
```